# How to test small program with user input in Haskell

Tags: haskell, testing

Im taking a software testing class. And we were allowed to choose what language to write our code and tests in. And I choose Haskell. I know, maybe not the best way to learn testing (= but...

The unit-testing and coding has been working great!

But I am also required to use mocking to get a higher grade.

My problem is that I don't know very much Haskell (like Monads and stuff).

I have written and tested Calculator. And now I want to test my main. My instructor used Mockito for Java to check that the program had the correct flow.

Is it possible to test that my if-statements are correct?
I have tried reading up on testing IO actions through Monads, but I don't quite understand it.
Maybe I should just learn more about Monads before trying to solve this?

Any help or reading suggestions are very much appreciated!

```
import Calculator

main :: IO ()
main = do
        putStrLn("What should I calculate? ex 3*(2+2)  | quit to exit" )
        line <- getLine
        if line /= "quit"
        then do if correctInput line
                then do putStrLn( show $ calculate line) 
                        main
                else do putStrLn "Wrong input" 
                        main
        else putStrLn "goodbye"
```

Comment: If mocking is part of the grade, your teacher probably should not have let you use Haskell in the first place. The idiomatic approach in Haskell is to use types that don't require you to mock anything in the first place.

Comment: I know that It would be much easier for me to get a higher grade if I would use Java or Python. But where is the fun in that (=. I dont really care about the grade, as long as i pass the course. I choose Haskell to learn more about Haskell.

Maybe I should try to convince him that mocking isn't really used in Haskell?

Comment: You could try anyway, even if it's not that idiomatic in Haskell. You could rename all the IO actions to use a module like `IO.putStrLn "..."`, and then `import System.IO as IO` or `import MyMockIO as IO` to switch to a custom mock-IO module you can write. I don't know if that would count as proper "mocking" as your instructor expects. Even if that does not work perfectly well, learning that it's not a very good idea could still be learning, and you could get credit for that, in theory. Asking your instructor in advance would be a good idea.

Comment: For very basic mocking, maybe you could even use the `pure-io` package, if you don't need very fancy IO. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pure-io-0.2.1/docs/PureIO.html

Comment: Lets say I create in MyMockIO 
IO.getLine = "1+2"
Im not sure how this helps me in my testing. I would need getLine to first return "1+2" and then "quit" otherwise we will be stuck in main forever.
@chi, but I guess I just dont understand what you mean.

Comment: In the mock, `IO` would be some sort of state monad, where you keep track of things like the list of all the previous outputs (e.g. `IO.putStrLn`), the number of times a line was read (`IO.getLine`). Essentially, `IO.getLine` should be able to inspect the current mock-IO state and return a string accordingly: in this way you can return "1+2" the first time and "quit" the second one. This is because each `IO.getLine` would alter the state (e.g. incrementing some counter), so that next time we now what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even in an object-oriented environment like Java or C# (my other specialty), one wouldn't be able to use [Test Doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double) ('mocks') on the `Main` method, since you can't do dependency injection on the entry point; its signature is fixed.

What you'd normally do would be to define a `MainImp` that takes dependencies, and then use Test Doubles to test that, leaving the actual `Main` method as a [Humble Executable](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html).

## Production code

You can do the same in Haskell. A simple approach is to do what *danidiaz* suggests, and simply pass impure actions as arguments to `mainImp`:

```
mainImp :: Monad m => m String -> (String -> m ()) -> m ()
mainImp getInput displayOutput = do
  displayOutput "What should I calcuclate? ex 3*(2+2)  | quit to exit" 
  line <- getInput
  if line /= "quit"
  then do if correctInput line
          then do displayOutput $ show $ calculate line
                  mainImp getInput displayOutput
          else do displayOutput "Wrong input"
                  mainImp getInput displayOutput
  else displayOutput "goodbye"
```

Notice that the type declaration explicitly allows any `Monad m`. This includes `IO`, which means that you can compose your actual `main` action like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = mainImp getLine putStrLn
```

In tests, however, you can use another monad. Usually, `State` is well-suited to this task.

## Tests

You can begin a test module with appropriate imports:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Test.HUnit.Base (Test(..), (~:), (~=?), (@?))
import Test.Framework (defaultMain)
import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit
import Q58750508

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain $ hUnitTestToTests $ TestList tests
```

This uses HUnit, and as you'll see in a while, I [inline the tests in a list literal](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/05/07/inlined-hunit-test-lists).

Before we get to the tests, however, I think it makes sense to define a test-specific type that can hold the state of the console:

```
data Console = Console { outputs :: [String], inputs :: [String] } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

You also need some functions that correspond to `getInput` and `displayOutput`, but that run in the `State Console` monad instead of in `IO`. This is [a technique that I've described before](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/03/11/an-example-of-state-based-testing-in-haskell).

```
getInput :: State Console String
getInput = do
  console <- get
  let input = head $ inputs console
  put $ console { inputs = tail $ inputs console }
  return input
```

Notice that this function is unsafe because it uses `head` and `tail`. I'll leave it as an exercise to make it safe.

It uses `get` to retrieve the current state of the console, pulls the `head` of the 'queue' of `inputs`, and updates the state before returning the `input`.

Likewise, you can implement `displayOutput` in the `State Console` monad:

```
displayOutput :: String -> State Console ()
displayOutput s = do
  console <- get
  put $ console { outputs = s : outputs console }
```

This just updates the state with the supplied `String`.

You're also going to need a way to run tests in the `State Console` monad:

```
runStateTest :: State Console a -> a
runStateTest = flip evalState $ Console [] []
```

This always kicks off any test with empty `inputs` and empty `outputs`, so it's your responsibility as a test writer to make sure that the `inputs` always ends with `"quit"`. You could also write a helper function to do that, or change `runStateTest` to always include this value.

A simple test, then, is:

```
tests :: [Test]
tests = [
  "Quit right away" ~: runStateTest $ do
    modify $ \console -> console { inputs = ["quit"] }

    mainImp getInput displayOutput

    Console actual _ <- get
    return $ elem "goodbye" actual @? "\"goodbye\" wasn't found in " ++ show actual
-- other tests go here...
]
```

This test just verifies that if you immediately `"quit"`, the `"goodbye"` message is present.

A slightly more involved test could be:

```
  ,
  "Run single calcuation" ~: runStateTest $ do
    modify $ \console -> console { inputs = ["3*(2+2)", "quit"] }

    mainImp getInput displayOutput

    Console actual _ <- get
    let expected =
          [ "What should I calcuclate? ex 3*(2+2)  | quit to exit",
            "12",
            "What should I calcuclate? ex 3*(2+2)  | quit to exit",
            "goodbye"]
    return $ expected ~=? reverse actual
```

You can insert it before the closing `]` in the above `tests` list, where the comment says `-- other tests go here...`.

I have more articles on unit testing with Haskell than the articles I've linked to, so be sure to follow the links there, as well as investigate what other articles inhabit the intersection between [the Haskell tag](https://blog.ploeh.dk/tags/#Haskell-ref) and [the Unit Testing tag](https://blog.ploeh.dk/tags/#Unit%20Testing-ref).

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed answer! I will hopefully get it to work.

Comment: Im not sure what to install so I can get these to work:

import Test.Framework (defaultMain)
import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit
import Q58750508

I tried http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF
but I get
Module ‘Test.Framework’ does not export ‘defaultMain’
Failed to load interface for ‘Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit’

Comment: I got it to work! 
I just needed to install this Test instead https://batterseapower.github.io/test-framework/ for: import Test.Framework (defaultMain)


 And http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-hunit for: import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit

But I still dont know why I need import Q58750508 or how to obtain it?

Comment: I do think this should be a completely new stackoverflow-post. But what is the best way to update  mainImp when main is changed?

Comment: @ErikTöger The test project in the above PoC has these dependencies, in addition to the SUT: *transformers, HUnit, test-framework, test-framework-hunit.* I don't understand the question about changing `main` - you don't change `main`, you change `mainImp`...

Comment: With main Im refering to my original code, the one mainImp is based of. mainImp is a copy of this main (I think I have moved it to meny in my code, through. But in the question it was still in main). So how do you keep mainImp up to date when the original code changes? Lets say our calculator now says farwell instead of goodbye. Changing this by hand in multiple places isnt very good practice.

Answer (score 4):

You can "mock" (or "fake") your dependencies without having to go beyond `IO`.

Your program logic interacts with the external world by way of `putStrLn` and `getLine`. But what does it know about them? Nothing, really, other than their types `String -> IO ()` and `IO String`.

So we can abstract them away, turning your program logic into a function `myProgramLogic :: (String -> IO ()) -> IO String -> IO ()` that receives the effectful actions as arguments. Passing dependencies as function arguments is a low-calorie version of dependency injection.

Now the problem becomes: how to mock `putStrLn` and `getLine`. Obviously the mocks can't be something interactive, as we want to do automated testing. But neither can they be boring actions like `\_ -> return ()` and `return "foo"` which always do the same thing. They must have state, they must keep a record of their interactions with the program logic.

There is a module called [`Data.IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html) in the standard library that lets you create and manipulate mutable references living in `IO`. What other languages would call "just a boring, run-of-the-mill variable".

This bit of code creates a mutable reference containing a list of strings, and also defines a `pseudoGetLine` function which extracts one of the strings each time it's executed:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    inputsRef <- newIORef ["foo","bar","baz"]
    let pseudoGetLine :: IO String
        pseudoGetLine = do
            atomicModifyIORef inputsRef (\inputs ->
                case inputs of
                    i : is -> (is,i) -- the i becomes the return value of pseudoGetLine 
                    [] -> error "fake inputs exhausted")
    sample <- pseudoGetLine
    print sample
```

You can see where this is going: after faking both dependencies and passing them to your logic, you can inspect the states of the mutable references (using a function like [`readIORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:readIORef)) in order to check that they are the expected ones.

Comment: here is what I have done so far:
[https://repl.it/@erikTeacher/Checking-Flow]

I  dont think this is what you intended though. But my code maybe shows how little Haskell I do know, so that It is easier for you (or others) to point me to relevant learning material.

Comment: @ErikTöger There's no need to use `unsafePerformIO` or to make the mutable references and functions top-level. Just create them in the `IO` do-block that holds your test and your assertions, it's easier that way. The references don't need to survive the test itself, after all. `pseudoGetLine` can also be defined within the block and passed as an argument inside the block. This link explains how `let`s let you create local definitions in a do-block https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation#Example:_user-interactive_program

Comment: thanks! I have now updated the code in the repl.
My next step will be to write code that modifies my original meny to create the mockmeny code. So that when  I change my orginal meny code, the mockmeny code also change.

Comment: @ErikTöger About `mockmeny` in repl.it. The point of mocking is keeping the *exact same business logic* that you use in reality, and *only substitute the dependencies*. But you are tying your logic irrevocably to how you define `pseudoPutStrLn`. You cease to be able to use the real `putStrLn`! Make your business logic a separate top level function that takes the print and read actions as parameters. Then you can either pass the *real* `putStrLn` and `readLine` (for actual use) or the mocked ones that you create inside your test.